# How can a ContinueWith task catch exception of C# task that returns void?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

How can a ContinueWith task catch the exception of a C# async task that returns void? (We're using VS 2010, so no async/await keywords yet). Our standard pattern when the task returns something is:

```
Task<int> task = ...;
task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
   try
   {
      int result = task.Result; //This will throw if there was an error.
      //Otherwise keep processing
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   { ... }
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

But if the task doesn't return anything, there is no "task.Result". So what's the best way to handle that task that doesn't return anything?

EDIT: Here's what I want to accomplish:

```
Task taskWithNoReturnType = ...
taskWithNoReturnType.ContinueWith( t =>
{
   try
   {
      //HOW CAN I KNOW IF THERE WAS AN EXCEPTION ON THAT TASK???

      //Otherwise, keep processing this callback
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   { ... }
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: `if(task.IsFaulted) {do something with task.Exception}`

Comment: Yeah, but that won't give me an error message or any information about why the task failed.

Answer (score 3):

[Task.Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception(v=vs.110%29.aspx) gets the [AggregateException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110%29.aspx) that caused the Task to end prematurely. If the Task completed successfully or has not yet thrown any exceptions, this will return null.

Example:

```
Task.Factory
       .StartNew(
            () => { DoSomething(); /* throws an exception */ } )
       .ContinueWith(
            p =>
            {
                if (p.Exception != null)
                    p.Exception.Handle(x =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
                            return true;
                        });
            });
```

Comment: The key points in this is the `p.Exception != null`  to check to see if there is a exception and the `p.Exception.Handle(` to get in the "catch block" for each exception thrown inside the original task. (Those points where not super clear to me from the text of the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer --

```
Task taskWithNoReturnType = ...
taskWithNoReturnType.ContinueWith( t =>
{
   try
   {
      t.Wait(); //This is the key. The task has already completed (we 
      //are in the .ContinueWith() after all) so this won't really wait,
      //but it will force any pending exceptions to propogate up and 
      //then the catch will work normally. 

      //Else, if we get here, then there was no exception.
      //<process code normally here>
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   { ... }
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```